# Unable to call MVC controller method for larger data using $.post in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, post

I am calling a method in MVC controller using $.post. i am passing an array of object to the controller using post method.
when the length of the array exceeds certain number, i think aroung 136 the method in MVC controller is not getting called. i am not getting any error as well.
so can anyone please provide me a solution for it.
i have attached the sample code below

```
     $http.post('Controller/Method', {
                data: CollectionOfObject
            }).
           success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              alert("success");                       
           }).
           error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              alert("error");
           });
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to do some basic troubleshooting and provide more information than this. If you don't get error then why do you think problem exists with the `$http` post?

Comment: Try increasing the size of maxAllowedContentLength in Web.config. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: @charlietfl i placed debugger in both angularJS side and in the MVC controller , the method in MVC controller is not getting called, In angularJS it is executing without any error, how do you want me to find out what the error is. thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know it's not being called? Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network and see what status is, what is sent, received etc.

Comment: i found the solution adding <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" /> to the webconfig fixed the issue. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding to webconfig the following lines fixed the problem.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```